# How to use a matrix with a circle as a mask?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm new in MATLAB and using it for some medical analysis. I have a matrix which contains a circular shape in it. Here is a sample:

```
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This matrix has been computed by this line:

```matlab
egslbr= edge(slbr,'log');
```

Where slbr is my image. By merging the egslbr with my slbr I get the image bellow.

[image]

I want to cancel all the color pixel outside the greenish circle. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a mask from your circle (assuming it's a complete circle -- the sample matrix you gave has a gap in it which makes this much more difficult, but I'm going to assume that was a mistake). Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
mask = ~cumsum(egslbr) | ~cumsum(egslbr,'reverse');
slbr(mask) = 0;
```

This should set every pixel outside the circle (*not* including the edge of the circle though) to zero.